# Export Azure key vault secrets as json list (or file)

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

Azure powershell - how to create json file with azure keyvaults secrets
(I know how to read the secrets with power shell).  I do know how to put key values pairs and export as a file.
So, given I have this

```
    secret1Name - secret1Value
    secret2Name - secret2Value
    secret3Name - secret3Value
```

I need a file saved to the file system

```
{
  "secret1Name":"secret1Value",
  "secret2Name":"secret2Value",
  "secret3Name":"secret3Value",
}
```

I found that there is something like this for reading from a file

```
$globalParametersJson = Get-Content $globalParametersFilePath
$globalParametersObject = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($globalParametersJson)
```

And I (think) i need help doing it for writing a file.
Can anyone help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Export Azure key vault secrets as json list (or file)

I have tried to reproduce your ask and I have received expected results:

What I have understood from your question is that you want to write a secret to file (then below is the answer for that).

Firstly, created an empty Json file and copied its path and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-9.2.0).

Then I executed the below script:

```
$y="C:\Users\vs\emo.json"
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "rithkey"
$secretnames=$secret.Name
$Target = @()
$result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
foreach($em in $secretnames )
{
$Target=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName rithkey -Name $em

$x=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName rithkey -AsPlainText -Name $em

$result | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $Target.Name  -Value $x
}
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $y
```

[image]

Now we can check file emo.json as we used `Set-Content` to write to emo.json file and output is below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you !!  It works.
Allow me this question, then.
Given it is a key vault with 'secrets'.  
Is it a good idea to have the key vault file created this way, then modified for other environments (UAT, QA, etc..) by someone within the organization with the right roles and then when those environments are created using Azure dev ops having a power shell task creating the new key vault in those environments ?